# finding people with a good network

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a table describing who knows whom.
The table contains rows like "Peter knows Mary". 
(The rows are not duplicate, so "Mary knows Peter" is not in the table because it is the same).
This a m*m matrix.
Now I want to make a subgroup: all people with a big social network.

For this, I can select all people wich know 10 or more other people.
But maybe Allan knows 10 people but these 10 people only know Allan and nobody else. So Allan knows only lonesome people and he has not a good social network.

So the recursive definition for my subgroup is: it contains all people who know 10 or more people from this subgroup.

The iterative solution is:
1. put all people into subgroup
2. reduce subgroup to people knowing at least 10 other
3. goto 2

Is there a solution without iteration?

(Note: I do not process personal data nor do I have data from real people.  This is only to describe the mathematical problem)

Comment: Search for "methods for community detection in graphs/networks" here, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and elsewhere.  There is a large literature!  This question is probably better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tagged this "linear algebra" because it is dealing with sparse symmetric matrices. I have the guess that this has something to do with the rank and eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252541/community-detection-in-network,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112118/community-detection-in-mobile-social-network,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266493/clustering-a-fully-connected-graph,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209086/community-detection-and-modularity,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15824/what-is-the-difference-between-graph-clustering-and-community-detection-methods   and a host of others!

Comment: Thank you for looking this up. I have a m × m matrix and I cannot make the moore-penrose-inverse if it contains too much missings so I have to reduce it.

Comment: You might be interested in the PageRank algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

Comment: Thank you, the page rank is a similar thing, but page links are not symmetric, a link from A to B is not the same as from B to A.